# decrease/increase the width of dropdown list (option tag)

Tags: html, css, forms

How can i change the width of dropdown menu. i'm able to change the width of select tag but not the option tag.

i tried this but no use

```
.box-wrapper select option{
    width:100px;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Better use some plugins. It's hard to style form elements (like select or checkbox)

Answer (score 1):

This works fine if the following `css` is added to your code

```
select{
   width:100px;
}

option{
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: Not really, the `option` gets `select` width - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gB85Z/2)

Comment: may b u should try and see @Vucko

Comment: I did try, see the fiddle.

Comment: oops this is working with firefox and not in chrome.. :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien didn't know that chrome has issues with this. Is there a cross browser solution?

Comment: @Mr.Alien neither did I, but I found this problem really interesting :)

Comment: @Vucko No, that's a bug since long time, see [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82253) for `max-width`